# SocialAuth integration using Django and React with Azure

Tags: reactjs, django, azure

My URL folder is as follows:

```
path("dj-rest-auth/", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
path("dj-rest-auth/azure/", azure_login.as_view(), name="azure_login"),
```

views.py as follows

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.azure.views import AzureOAuth2Adapter
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class azure_login(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = AzureOAuth2Adapter
```

When I navigate to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dj-rest-auth/azure/`, How can I pass these values from the frontend react code?

```
  const handleAzureLogin = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      const codeParams = { "code": "AAAAA" }; What should I do here?

      const { data } = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/dj-rest-auth/azure/`, codeParams);
      console.log(data)
      window.location.href = data.url;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);      
      console.log('Error response data:', err.response.data);

    }
  };
```